MAUI library for Native Android binding failing with aar files that have Java Interfaces
I recently started working on MAUI Android binding library.
I have created an aar file which has a simple Kotlin class and an Interface. This interface is implemented by the Kotlin class.
The simple Kotlin class
package com.app.mauitestlib

import android.util.Log

class MauiLibTest: MauiTestListener {


    fun start(initKey: String) {
        Log.d("MauiTest", "start called: ")
    }

    override fun onInit() {
        Log.d("MauiTest", "onInit")
    }

}

The simple Kotlin Interface
package com.app.mauitestlib

interface MauiTestListener {

    fun onInit()

}


Using Android Studio, I have generated mauitestlib-release.aar file.
My requirement is to bind the aar file generated to MAUI library using net8.0-android target framework. I have the following setup for MAUI library

The wfx-maui-test.csproj looks like this.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-android</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>wfx_maui_test</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PackOnBuild>true</PackOnBuild>
        <PackageId>Maui.Android.Test</PackageId>
        <PackageVersion>0.0.3</PackageVersion>
        <Authors>Test</Authors>
        <Owners>Test</Owners>
        <Description>MAUI Test SDK</Description>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <Configurations>Release;Debug</Configurations>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SkipValidateMauiImplicitPackageReferences>true</SkipValidateMauiImplicitPackageReferences>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Packaging">
        <Version>0.2.2</Version>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <AndroidLibrary Include="Jars\mauitestlib-release.aar" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>


To build this library, I run the following commands,

dotnet clean wfx-maui-test.csproj
dotnet restore wfx-maui-test.csproj
dotnet build -c Release


This generates dll files without any error, but when i publish the library to nuget as library and use it in a MAUI Android project. It fails the following error.
obj/Debug/net8.0-android/android/src/mono/com/app/mauitestlib/MauiTestListenerImplementor.java(8,22): javac error JAVAC0000:  error: package com.app.mauitestlib does not exist


Debugging so far
Upon debugging, I found that a cs file name Com.App.Mauitestlib.IMauiTestListener.cs is generated which has the below code.

[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("mono/com/app/mauitestlib/MauiTestListenerImplementor")]
internal sealed partial class IMauiTestListenerImplementor : global::Java.Lang.Object, IMauiTestListener {

}


This is internally registering java file name MauiTestListenerImplementor.java under the package mono/com/app/mauitestlib which is causing the issue.
How i make sure that the file is not registered under mono/com/app/mauitestlib package?
How can i make my maui library work with aar file that has Kotlin/Java interface?

try changing: wfx_maui_test to wfx.maui.test

Also try adding: true and remove: true

Hi @o_w, I have tried this but the issue still persist. Heres what i have tried.
true
and changed from LibraryProjectZip to AndroidLibrary.


